# how can I use pandas to plot the graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have this length.csv file content:

[image]

May I know how can I use pandas plot dot graph base on this xy and yx?

Comment: Please dont post your sample data as screenshots.
Follow the guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

What plot are you exactly looking for.
There are multiple possibilities with pandas plot as mentioned here:(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\to\folder\length.csv')
```

Now if you print df, you will get the following

[image]

```
df.plot(x='yx', y='xy', kind='scatter')
```

[image]

You can change your plot type to different types like line, bar etc.
Refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `matplotlib`. The `plot` method in `Pandas` is a wrapper for `matplotlib`.

If you wish to use `Pandas`, you can do it as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('length.csv')

df.plot(x='xy', y='yx')
```

If you decide to go ahead with `matplotlib`, you can do as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline # Include this line only if on a notebook (like Jupyter or Colab)

df = pd.read_csv('length.csv')

plt.plot(df['xy'], df['yx'])
plt.xlabel('xy')
plt.ylabel('yx')
plt.title('xy vs yx Plot')

plt.show()
```

Comment: How about if I want to plot a dot graph? Then may I know how to plot it?